# Bootcamp won't boot after resizing partitions

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, partition

I know this question has been asked a lot, but my situation seems to be a little different than most of the others I have been reading about. I haven't been able to find a solution that could fix this issue.

Basically, I created another ExFAT partition for universal storage between both OS's, and now Bootcamp won't load. I was aware of the issues with the Hybrid MBR changing after repartitioning, but I figured I could fix it after I resized.

I tried the guides [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29579529#29579529) and [here](http://nerdr.com/bootcamp-partition-lost-repairing-mac-partitions/), which are so far the two main methods I could find online, with most of the others being a variation of the two. Both haven't worked for me.

Here is some info that might help to diagnose the issue:

I'm running Mac OS 10.11.6 and Windows 10. I can see the Bootcamp partition in Finder, and it does show up under startup drives in Settings. A lot of people who have this problem don't seem to be able to see either, so that is different. Also, I have rEFInd installed, so I don't know if that makes a difference either. SIP is also disabled.

Here is some terminal output:

**diskutil list**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            350.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data STORAGE                 98.2 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                49.9 GB    disk0s5
   6:           Windows Recovery                         471.9 MB   disk0s6
```

**diskutil cs list**

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

**sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0**

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500277790720; sectorsize=512; blocks=977105060
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 977105059
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         MBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  684863280      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
685272920    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
686542456  191828360      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
878370816     262144         
878632960   97550336      5  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
976183296     921600      6  GPT part - DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
977104896        131         
977105027         32         Sec GPT table
977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

**sudo fdisk /dev/disk0**

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
     Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]

 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  685272919] <Unknown ID>
 2: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 685272920 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
 3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 686542456 -  191828360] HPFS/QNX/AUX
*4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 878632960 -   97550336] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

Note that it may look a bit different than others' situations because I have already tried various solutions, such as the above code block. When I try to boot Windows, it comes up with:

> Recovery
>   Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
>   An unexpected error has occurred.
>   Error code: 0xc000000e
>   You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation >media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or >PC/Device manufacturer.

I was wondering whether I need to either repair the partition or set a boot partition within Windows using a bootable USB/DVD.

How can I make Bootcamp boot again?

Comment: I posted the same question on the Apple community, and a genius over there was able to solve the problem. You can find it [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7695245).